# Ignoring a @MappedSuperclass for not extended class JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

If for example I have two class **FullTimeEmployee** and **PartTimeEmployee** . **FullTimeEmployee** has to extend **Employee** table and to access that properties by using **@MappedSuperclass** but **PartTimeEmployee** class does not required any extend but it throws **JPA error** if not extended all the other classes.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Employee {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private long id;
      private String name;
        .............
}

@Entity
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
  private int salary;
    .............
}
```

I don't want to extended **PartTimeEmployee** class with employee **@MappedSuperclass** does not allow me to do that

```
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee {
  private int hourlyRate;
    .............
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more.What exception is coming and what do you want to achieve.As per your question PartTimeEmployee  is independent entity which will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reconsider your desing and entity naming. If your `PartTimeEmployee` does not extend `Employee` you need at least the `id` so:

```
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private int hourlyRate;
    . . .
}
```

**OR** you could also create a bit more cleverdesign and a mapped superclass like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
```

Thne your `Employee` could extend it and inherit `id`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    . . .
}
```

Your `FullTimeEmployee` could be as it is and `PartTimeEmployee` could extend `BaseEntity` to inherit `id`:

```
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee extends BaseEntity {
    private int hourlyRate;
. . .
}
```